# Is this the correct way to sort using XSLT?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt, .net-3.5

Basically what's happening is that the XML nodes themselves aren't changing position. So I figured my XSLT was missing something.

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:asp="http://test.com/asp"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="asp:TableRow">
                <xsl:sort select="@ID" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns:asp="http://test.com/asp" xmlns:meta="http://test.com/meta" xmlns:cc1="http://test.com/cc1">
  <asp:TableRow ID="A02">
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagthreeCtrlNumberRes" meta:resourcekey="tagthreeCtrlNumberRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagthreeCtrlDescRes" meta:resourcekey="tagthreeCtrlDescRes" runat="server" />
      <asp:Localize ID="tagthreeCtrlNoteRes" meta:resourcekey="tagthreeCtrlNoteRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblthreeCtrlRes0" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl0Res0" Value="1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="No" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl1Res0" Value="0" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="N/A" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl2Res0" Value="2" />
      </asp:RadioButtonList>
      <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblthreeCtrlRes1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl0Res1" Value="1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="No" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl1Res1" Value="0" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="N/A" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl2Res1" Value="2" />
      </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Button ID="cmdthreeCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="cmdthreeCtrlRes" runat="server" OnClick="FormDataSave_Click" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="lblAssmthreeCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="lblAssmthreeCtrlRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="lblQualthreeCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="lblQualthreeCtrlRes" runat="server" />
      <asp:Button ID="cmdQualAcceptthreeCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="cmdQualAcceptthreeCtrlRes" OnClick="cmdQualAccept_Click" runat="server" Text="Accept" Visible="True" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell />
    <asp:TableCell />
  </asp:TableRow>
  <asp:TableRow ID="A01">
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagtwoCtrlNumberRes" meta:resourcekey="tagtwoCtrlNumberRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagtwoCtrlDescRes" meta:resourcekey="tagtwoCtrlDescRes" runat="server" />
      <asp:Localize ID="tagtwoCtrlNoteRes" meta:resourcekey="tagtwoCtrlNoteRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagtxttwoCtrlRes0" meta:resourcekey="tagtxttwoCtrlRes0" runat="server" />
      <asp:Textbox ID="txttwoCtrlRes0" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Button ID="cmdtwoCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="cmdtwoCtrlRes" runat="server" OnClick="FormDataSave_Click" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="lblAssmtwoCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="lblAssmtwoCtrlRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell />
    <asp:TableCell />
    <asp:TableCell />
  </asp:TableRow>
  <asp:TableRow ID="A03">
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagoneCtrlNumberRes" meta:resourcekey="tagoneCtrlNumberRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagoneCtrlDescRes" meta:resourcekey="tagoneCtrlDescRes" runat="server" />
      <asp:Localize ID="tagoneCtrlNoteRes" meta:resourcekey="tagoneCtrlNoteRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagtxtoneCtrlRes0" meta:resourcekey="tagtxtoneCtrlRes0" runat="server" />
      <asp:Textbox ID="txtoneCtrlRes0" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Button ID="cmdoneCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="cmdoneCtrlRes" runat="server" OnClick="FormDataSave_Click" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="lblAssmoneCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="lblAssmoneCtrlRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell />
    <asp:TableCell />
    <asp:TableCell />
  </asp:TableRow>
</Root>
```

Code-behind:

```
For Each deleteChild As XmlNode In rootDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes
    rootDoc.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(deleteChild)
Next

'List (Of XMLNode)'
For Each markupElem As XmlElement In allNodes
    rootDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(markupElem)
Next

'List (Of XMLNode)'
For Each markupElem As XmlElement In nodesToMove
    rootDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(markupElem)
Next

Dim sortXmlDoc As Xsl.XslCompiledTransform = New Xsl.XslCompiledTransform(True)
sortXmlDoc.Load(xsltPath)

Dim saveWriter As XmlTextWriter = New XmlTextWriter(truePath, Nothing)
sortXmlDoc.Transform(rootDoc, saveWriter)
saveWriter.Close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are two obvious problem with the provided code**:

1. The only template in the code is matching `root`, but there is no `root` element at all in the provided XML element -- therefore this template isn't selected for execution at all.
2. The elements in the provided XML document have no text nodes children. As there isn't any other template in the provided XSLT code, only the built-in XSLT templates are used in processing the XML document. Their effect is to copy to the output only the text nodes -- so nothing is produced as output.

**Solution**:

1. Change `match='root'` to `match='Root'`.
2. Add the identity rule, so that every node will be copied.

**Having applied these two corrections to your code it becomes**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:asp="http://test.com/asp"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Root">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="asp:TableRow">
                <xsl:sort select="@ID" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Root xmlns:asp="http://test.com/asp" xmlns:meta="http://test.com/meta" xmlns:cc1="http://test.com/cc1">
  <asp:TableRow ID="A02">
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagthreeCtrlNumberRes" meta:resourcekey="tagthreeCtrlNumberRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagthreeCtrlDescRes" meta:resourcekey="tagthreeCtrlDescRes" runat="server" />
      <asp:Localize ID="tagthreeCtrlNoteRes" meta:resourcekey="tagthreeCtrlNoteRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblthreeCtrlRes0" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl0Res0" Value="1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="No" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl1Res0" Value="0" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="N/A" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl2Res0" Value="2" />
      </asp:RadioButtonList>
      <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblthreeCtrlRes1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl0Res1" Value="1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="No" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl1Res1" Value="0" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="N/A" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl2Res1" Value="2" />
      </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Button ID="cmdthreeCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="cmdthreeCtrlRes" runat="server" OnClick="FormDataSave_Click" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="lblAssmthreeCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="lblAssmthreeCtrlRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="lblQualthreeCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="lblQualthreeCtrlRes" runat="server" />
      <asp:Button ID="cmdQualAcceptthreeCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="cmdQualAcceptthreeCtrlRes" OnClick="cmdQualAccept_Click" runat="server" Text="Accept" Visible="True" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell />
    <asp:TableCell />
  </asp:TableRow>
  <asp:TableRow ID="A01">
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagtwoCtrlNumberRes" meta:resourcekey="tagtwoCtrlNumberRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagtwoCtrlDescRes" meta:resourcekey="tagtwoCtrlDescRes" runat="server" />
      <asp:Localize ID="tagtwoCtrlNoteRes" meta:resourcekey="tagtwoCtrlNoteRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagtxttwoCtrlRes0" meta:resourcekey="tagtxttwoCtrlRes0" runat="server" />
      <asp:Textbox ID="txttwoCtrlRes0" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Button ID="cmdtwoCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="cmdtwoCtrlRes" runat="server" OnClick="FormDataSave_Click" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="lblAssmtwoCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="lblAssmtwoCtrlRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell />
    <asp:TableCell />
    <asp:TableCell />
  </asp:TableRow>
  <asp:TableRow ID="A03">
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagoneCtrlNumberRes" meta:resourcekey="tagoneCtrlNumberRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagoneCtrlDescRes" meta:resourcekey="tagoneCtrlDescRes" runat="server" />
      <asp:Localize ID="tagoneCtrlNoteRes" meta:resourcekey="tagoneCtrlNoteRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagtxtoneCtrlRes0" meta:resourcekey="tagtxtoneCtrlRes0" runat="server" />
      <asp:Textbox ID="txtoneCtrlRes0" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Button ID="cmdoneCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="cmdoneCtrlRes" runat="server" OnClick="FormDataSave_Click" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="lblAssmoneCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="lblAssmoneCtrlRes" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell />
    <asp:TableCell />
    <asp:TableCell />
  </asp:TableRow>
</Root>
```

**the wanted, correct (sorted) result is produced**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<root xmlns:asp="http://test.com/asp">
<asp:TableRow ID="A01" xmlns:meta="http://test.com/meta" xmlns:cc1="http://test.com/cc1">
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagtwoCtrlNumberRes" meta:resourcekey="tagtwoCtrlNumberRes" runat="server"></asp:Localize>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagtwoCtrlDescRes" meta:resourcekey="tagtwoCtrlDescRes" runat="server"></asp:Localize>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagtwoCtrlNoteRes" meta:resourcekey="tagtwoCtrlNoteRes" runat="server"></asp:Localize>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagtxttwoCtrlRes0" meta:resourcekey="tagtxttwoCtrlRes0" runat="server"></asp:Localize>
      <asp:Textbox ID="txttwoCtrlRes0" runat="server"></asp:Textbox>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Button ID="cmdtwoCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="cmdtwoCtrlRes" runat="server" OnClick="FormDataSave_Click"></asp:Button>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="lblAssmtwoCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="lblAssmtwoCtrlRes" runat="server"></asp:Localize>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
  </asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableRow ID="A02" xmlns:meta="http://test.com/meta" xmlns:cc1="http://test.com/cc1">
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagthreeCtrlNumberRes" meta:resourcekey="tagthreeCtrlNumberRes" runat="server"></asp:Localize>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagthreeCtrlDescRes" meta:resourcekey="tagthreeCtrlDescRes" runat="server"></asp:Localize>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagthreeCtrlNoteRes" meta:resourcekey="tagthreeCtrlNoteRes" runat="server"></asp:Localize>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblthreeCtrlRes0" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl0Res0" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="No" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl1Res0" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="N/A" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl2Res0" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:RadioButtonList>
      <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblthreeCtrlRes1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl0Res1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="No" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl1Res1" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="N/A" meta:resourcekey="rblthreeCtrl2Res1" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Button ID="cmdthreeCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="cmdthreeCtrlRes" runat="server" OnClick="FormDataSave_Click"></asp:Button>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="lblAssmthreeCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="lblAssmthreeCtrlRes" runat="server"></asp:Localize>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="lblQualthreeCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="lblQualthreeCtrlRes" runat="server"></asp:Localize>
      <asp:Button ID="cmdQualAcceptthreeCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="cmdQualAcceptthreeCtrlRes" OnClick="cmdQualAccept_Click" runat="server" Text="Accept" Visible="True"></asp:Button>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
  </asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableRow ID="A03" xmlns:meta="http://test.com/meta" xmlns:cc1="http://test.com/cc1">
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagoneCtrlNumberRes" meta:resourcekey="tagoneCtrlNumberRes" runat="server"></asp:Localize>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagoneCtrlDescRes" meta:resourcekey="tagoneCtrlDescRes" runat="server"></asp:Localize>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagoneCtrlNoteRes" meta:resourcekey="tagoneCtrlNoteRes" runat="server"></asp:Localize>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="tagtxtoneCtrlRes0" meta:resourcekey="tagtxtoneCtrlRes0" runat="server"></asp:Localize>
      <asp:Textbox ID="txtoneCtrlRes0" runat="server"></asp:Textbox>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Button ID="cmdoneCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="cmdoneCtrlRes" runat="server" OnClick="FormDataSave_Click"></asp:Button>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Localize ID="lblAssmoneCtrlRes" meta:resourcekey="lblAssmoneCtrlRes" runat="server"></asp:Localize>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
  </asp:TableRow>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Dimitre: Thank you again, for helping me out. Do you have a book or something? I'd buy it. I had to do a change to the code-behind. This is the change:

```
Dim xsltPath As String = Server.MapPath(xsltFileName3)

Dim sortXmlDoc As Xsl.XslCompiledTransform = New Xsl.XslCompiledTransform(True)
sortXmlDoc.Load(xsltPath)
Dim output = sortXmlDoc.OutputSettings

Dim saveWriter As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(truePath, output)
sortXmlDoc.Transform(markup, saveWriter)
saveWriter.Close()
```

The variable "markup" is a XmlDocument. After writing to the XmlWriter, I found out I cannot do markup.Save. It will write the data to the XML file again and in the wrong order as well. Because of the way the code-behind behaved, I made a slight change to the XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:asp="http://test.com/asp"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Root">
        <Root xmlns:asp="http://test.com/asp" xmlns:meta="http://test.com/meta" xmlns:cc1="http://test.com/cc1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="asp:TableRow">
                <xsl:sort select="@ID" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @_dotnetN00b: You are welcome. (I have my recommendations on XSLT/XPAth books here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589